# Nested dictionary key and values

Tags: python, key, key-value

```
mydict = {'Papa': {12: {45: {'AG'}}}}
mydict['Rocks']['Big'] = 'black'
>>>print(mydict)
{'Papa': {Marbles: {Small: {'blue'}}}, {'Rocks': {'Big': {'black'}}

[evaluate asdf.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Justin/asdf.py", line 2, in <module>
    mydict['Rocks']['Big'] = 'black'
builtins.KeyError: 'Rocks'
```

I'm getting a key error...

Comment: You should show the code that produces the error, and the actual error.

Comment: Fixed it! Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `KeyError: 'Rocks'` since you are going to add `black` for key `Big` which is nested by `Rock` and `Rock` doesn't exist yet

To solve this you may add this line instead of current one

```
mydict['Rocks']={'Big' : {'black'}}
```

This will add `{'Big' : {'black'}}` for key value `Rock` not the sub key `Big` as you tried in your code snippet.

Try the output by entering

```
print(mydict['Rocks']['Big'])
```

and it will output `{'black'}`